# How do I apply wsgi module on an Apache on Mac OS?

Tags: mod-wsgi

Hello I installed on a MacBook Pro Apache httpd 2.4, mysql, ssl and I need to install or add the module wsgi.

I'm new to this server, this server is implemented on Windows computers but apparently the wsgi file must be different for this type operating systems.

I tried the test-cgi and I made a hello world with perl and apparently is well done the alias.

I do not quite understand it if they can recomender me a good book of wsgi or give me a brief explanation ...

I found a hello world .wsgi

```
    # Library Im
    import cgi, sys, os

    path =  os.path.dirname(__file__)

    if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

    # Own Libraries
    def application(env, resp):
    cgi.test()
```

I found plenty to talk about Django nose if this is required ...
I appreciate your help.